Movie about a house that is alive and starts killing people
I remember seeing this movie back in the 90s. 
The movie takes place in a mansion and the house is alive.  Either the house invites guests or the guests break in but I remember the guests being fairly young.  The house has cameras and can see what is going on inside it.  I remember a swimming pool.  The house starts killing people and they can't get out of the house.  At the very end the house is on fire and two people end up getting out but as they reach the gate two giant black tubes come out from somewhere and grab one of them.  They talk the house into letting them go by reasoning with it and it lets them go and lets itself continue to burn.

It seems you have created two different unregistered accounts. You might want to register one of your accounts and merge the two by following the procedure described here, in order to properly manage your post, including being able to edit, comment and accept any possible answers.

NEVERMIND, I did more research and FINALLY found it. It was a made for TV movie called "This House Possessed" 1981. Hooray for the internet.

After having a nervous breakdown, a rock singer has to spend some time in hospital. A private nurse is hired, and with her he buys a new house, a fantastic house in the country. The nurse, Sheila, can't remember the first years of her life, but this house seems strangely familiar to her. Also, there is this strange old woman who claims that Sheila's real name is Margaret. People who cause Sheila pain or who try to tell her the real story of what happened in this house, they die in strange ways: Tanya, the girlfriend of the singer, and the Library woman who wants to give her some newspaper articles. Can Sheila find out the truth behind all this and can she escape the house that possessed once and wants to possess once more? 


Quite a few movies like that have been released, but here are a few from the 1990's. Your description has elements from both of these movies. I hope this list at least narrows it down.
House on Haunted Hill
The Haunting 

Thank you, but it seems the OP already found their movie and answered their own question.
